# StencilJS passing in array of objects from React

Tags: reactjs

I have a stencil component that takes an array of objects to display. I am trying to pass that array in from my react app, [and have been following this example to do that](https://stenciljs.com/docs/react). If i log the component with the array passed in, i can see that it appears to be formed correctly.

[image: console log display of component]

The actual component I built to create the reference to handle the array is where my problem is, and I just can't figure out where I made the mistake, as there is an issue with the example.  My component inside my react app, which returns the stencil component is as follows

```
const ActionBar: React.FC<{ pageActions: pageActionsObj }> = ({ pageActions }) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (elementRef.current).pageActionList = pageActions;
  }, [pageActions]);

  return <pw-actionbar ref={elementRef}></pw-actionbar>;
};
```

and I try to use it as a regular component as such

```
<ActionBar pageActions={pageActionsObj}/>
```

Where the array that im passing as the prop is

```
export const pageActionsObj = [
    {
        name: "Users",
        page: "partner",
        icon: "pw-i-filled-multiple-users",
        onpage: false
    },
    {
        name: "Billing",
        page: "billing",
        icon: "pw-i-filled-billing",
        onpage: false
    },
    {
        name: "Helpdesk",
        page: "help-desk",
        icon: "pw-i-filled-help",
        onpage: false
    },
    {
        name: "My Profile",
        page: "profile",
        icon: "pw-i-filled-user",
        onpage: true
    },
    {
        name: "Sign Out",
        page: "sign-out",
        icon: "pw-i-filled-sign-out",
        onpage: false
    },
];
```

I very strongly believe that the way the component is set up, paired with the way I am passing in the array as a prop is causing the issue. I have been stuck for hours. What am i missing?